# Automatically Zoom the map to fit all markers

Tags: leaflet, markerclusterer

Following an example, you can see the plunker her http://plnkr.co/edit/lJHyP3dhT3v8aHVdt3D3?p=preview

Regardless of whatever zoom value is provided while initializitng the map, I want to zoom the map automatically so all the markers are inside the view. Here is my code

```
var tiles = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Points &copy 2012 LINZ'
    }),
    latlng = L.latLng(-37.82, 175.24);

var map = L.map('map', {center: latlng, zoom: 10, layers: [tiles]});

var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
    var a = addressPoints[i];
    var title = a[2];
    var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), { title: title });
    marker.bindPopup(title);
    markers.addLayer(marker);
}

map.addLayer(markers);

var group = new L.featureGroup(markers);

map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to

- create an array
- push all your markers in array
- once all the markers are added to array, create a `featureGroup`
- add your markers array to `featureGroup` and then zoom to its bounds.

Below is the **modified** code

```
var markerArray = []; //create new markers array

for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
    var a = addressPoints[i];
    var title = a[2];
    var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), { title: title });
    marker.bindPopup(title);
    markers.addLayer(marker);

    markerArray.push(marker); //add each markers to array

    if(i==addressPoints.length-1){//this is the case when all the markers would be added to array
        var group = L.featureGroup(markerArray); //add markers array to featureGroup
        map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());   
    }
}
```

Here is the working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ViRVjm?p=preview)